# Sharepoint site still down even after restore the content databse to new web app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, web-application

We’ve a major issue in our main intranet portal. It’s down with a lot of errors that were not fixed by investigating on event viewer and ULS logs.

However, I’ve restored the content database to a date before the incident, but still the same issue was happening. So I created a new web app in the same farm and attached the main content database to it, but still I’m getting some errors as shown below:

Notes:

- The central admin is working fine, but the web app is down, and they are on the same server.
- The original web app name (which is down) is: http://sp-l1
- The new web app that I created and attached the db to it is: http://sp-l1:8080

Here is the error I’m getting when open the site:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> Unknown server tag 'dev:datetimelabel'.
>
> Correlation ID: cef1ea9e-da03-0010-814b-70100b22910d

When I search for the ID in the ULS logs, I get the below:

https://pastebin.com/raw/UZYW5wGf

Comment: Do you have any custom WSP packages deployed on the farm?
Try to retract wsp in central administration or via PowerShell

Comment: No, we don't have any WSPs deployed to this web app

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually caused by lack of registered assemblies in web config. Review the webconfig files and confirm that you have all necessary assemblies registered.

To further troubleshoot I would review the Windows event logs, and use process monitor to see what issues are occurring with your IIS process.

Comment: Thanks Marek for the quick response and your feedback. 

Could you please let me know what kind of assemblies do I need to register according to these errors. Sorry for that because I'm not an expert in SharePoint, I'm just trying to fix it as our SP admin is on emergency leave.

Comment: No I can't this label doesn't seems to be part of outOfTheBox, do probably have some custom solution deployed in your farm?

Comment: Using Process Monitor from sysInternals may help you identify what are you missing.

Comment: You could as well change the logging level for the ULS it may give you more information. Get-SPLogLevel #check logging lever
Clear-SPLogLevel  #set logging lever to default. 
Set-SPLogLevel -EventSeverity ie -TraceSeverity verboseex  #Set max level of logging.

Comment: Get yourself as well the uls log viewer it will help to make sense of the SP ULS Logs. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020

Comment: Thanks Marek So much, I will try these methods and see.

Comment: I checked the ULS logs and the procmon logs, all of them showing that shrepoint still pointing to the original web app, not the one I created. So, do you have any idea why I can see the old web app name in the log, and why it's related to the new web app anyway. Do I need to change it someweher in the iis console or the DB itself?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing the following:

- Get the GUID of your mounted content DB from the new web app.
- Get the GUID of your original Content DB from the new wep app.
- Update your mounted content DB GUID in the new web application with the help of your databases team or thru the PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

I've analyzed your log picture and want to notice that the issue is - *Exception trying get context compatibility level: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site http://sp-l1:80/ could not be found*

I suggest you to run the following Powershell code as described [here](http://wp.ahcheng.com/2014/03/10/exception-trying-get-context-compatibility-level-system-io-filenotfoundexception/).

```
 $tempSite = Get-SPDeletedSite
 $tempSite.Restore()
```

Comment: It gave me the below error. But I think this is different situation, as I detached the DB from the site http://sp-l1:80  and attached it to the new site http://sp-l1:8080

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $tempSite.Restore()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Did you create any site collection at  sp-l1:8080 before you mounted db? Try to dismount db from newly created web app. Create empty site collection, remove newly created db and mount restored db. Also try to perform Test-SPContentDatabase

Comment: I have dismount db from newly created web app. Create empty site collection, remove newly created db and mount restored db... but still getting the same error

Comment: So, why I can see the old web app name in the log, and why it's related to the new web app anyway. Do I need to change it someweher in the iis console or the DB itself?

Comment: I got this error in the uls logs as well

Comment: Application error when access /Pages/default.aspx, Error=Unknown server tag 'dev:datetimelabel'.   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessError(String message)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) 4701eb9e-5ac6-0010-814b-771a4e2e38da
System.Web.HttpException: Unknown server tag 'dev:datetimelabel'.    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessError(String message)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)

Comment: Try to perform Test-SPContentDatabase. Are there any errors in db?

Comment: I found some web parts are mission, but don't know how to install them, pls have a look into the output

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/32iQjHVc

Comment: I think - it may be root cause -  The [SharePoint - Portal - 8080] web application is configured with windows classic authentication mode however the content database you are trying to attach is intended to be used against a claims authentication mode.

Comment: Still the same issue, sorry Rak for disturbing you with my issue today. I'm still getting the same logs as in the below link

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/32iQjHVc